# vscode @see @link to a no imported module in isolate

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

Is there a way to get link in vscode for a module isolate ?

if i not import the symbole , but want link the module how i can do ?

i try many way without success

```
/**
 * @Component - main Renderer

 * @see {@link SystemRenderer}
 * {@link @SYSTEMS:SystemRenderer}
 * {@link module:SystemRenderer}

 */
```

the last one seem work but point me to global nodejs module !
am looking for a way to point to a no imported module in a isolate module.

It seem work only if i import the symbole in the file ! ?

[image]

thanks

Comment: How is the `SystemRenderer` declared? Is it declared in a Javascript file or Typescript?

Comment: typescript file